# how to solve double 403 response in web scraping with scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy, header

I try to get the articles from this website. What I have tried:

- get into the main url
- get into the sub url where the complete article is there
- get all the details I need from the complete article

But I got response 403 when I tried to run my code first, then I tried to fix it by adding headers when requesting to the `start_urls` as what I read from some answers. I did it, but then my script gives me error where it said response 403 when getting into the sub url where all the information I need is there.

My current code is below

```
import scrapy
from scrapy import Request
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess


class climateupdate(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'climateupdate'
    start_urls = ['http://www.bom.gov.au/climate/updates/']

    def start_requests(self):
        headers= {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:48.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/48.0'}
        for url in self.start_urls:
            yield Request(url, headers=headers)

    def parse(self, response):
        for link in response.xpath('//*[@id="content"]/ul/li[1]/a/@href'):
            yield response.follow(
                url=link.get(),
                callback=self.parse_item
            )
        

    def parse_item(self, response):
        yield {
            'date': response.xpath('//*[@id="updates"]/p[1]/time/text()').extract(),
            'title': response.xpath('//*[@id="updates"]/div[1]/h1/text()').get(),
            'text':''.join([x.get().strip() for x in response.xpath('//*[@class="key-points box-notice bg-grey"]//p//text()')])
            }
if __name__ == '__main__':
    process = CrawlerProcess()
    process.crawl(weeklymining)
    process.start()
```

How should I write my script in order to get into the sub url and get all the details regarding the articles.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Using headers here is incorrect that's why you are getting `403`
2. Use custom settings to inject user-agent
3. your `date and text` selecting xpath expressions are incorrect
4. `//*[@id="content"]/ul/li[1]/a/@href` selects only one details url

**Full working code:**

```
import scrapy
from scrapy import Request
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

class climateupdate(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'climateupdate'
    start_urls = ['http://www.bom.gov.au/climate/updates/']
    custom_settings = {
            'CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_DOMAIN': 1,
            'DOWNLOAD_DELAY': 1,
            'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'
            }

    def start_requests(self):
        for url in self.start_urls:
            yield Request(url,callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        for link in response.xpath('//*[@class="list-archive"]/li/a/@href'):
            yield response.follow(
                url=link.get(),
                callback=self.parse_item
            )
        

    def parse_item(self, response):
        yield {
            'date': response.xpath('//*[@id="updates"]/p[1]/time/text()').get(),
            'title': ''.join(response.xpath('//*[@id="updates"]//h1//text()').getall()).strip(),
            'text':''.join(response.xpath('//*[@id="updates"]//p//text()').getall()[1:]).strip()
            }
if __name__ == '__main__':
    process = CrawlerProcess()
    process.crawl(weeklymining)
    process.start()
```